# Linux Export Path bad subsitution

Tags: swift, linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to [install Swift in my Ubuntu 16.04](https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift). I used had a typo when trying to change the PATH, so I try to redo it:

```
export PATH=/path/to/Swift/usr/bin:"${~/Downloads/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/bin}"
```

But now the terminal is telling me that my command is incorrect:

> bash: ${~/Downloads/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/bin}: bad
>   substitution

Are there any fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that syntax is incorrect for `${...}`. Write like this:

```
export PATH=/path/to/Swift/usr/bin:~/Downloads/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Also, I appended `:$PATH` at the end, so that the new paths are added to your existing `PATH`, rather than replacing it completely.

Comment: Thank you. After I run this command, `mkdir` and `ls` don't work any more. Also I have to run this command every time I start my computer.

Comment: @HanjunChen I updated my answer. That should solve your problem with `mkdir` and `ls`. To run this every time you login, you can add the line at the end of the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

Comment: @HanjunChen do you need more help?